# How can we achieve this view in android?

Tags: android, eclipse, mobile, android-recyclerview

What is that in below image? I mean how can we achieve such views in android ? Is it `RecyclerView` ? or is that different views managed the way that looks ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use `StaggeredGridLayoutManager` [Official docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/StaggeredGridLayoutManager.html) and here is a nice [tutorial](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2015/07/staggeredgridlayoutmanager-google-app.html)